# Does sysctl [variable=[value]] have the same effect as sysctl -w [variable=[value]]?

Tags: command-line, systemd

I know `sysctl [variable]` such as `sysctl vm.swappiness` will print out the value of `vm.swappiness`. But when I tried `sysctl vm.swappiness=10` and then typed `sysctl vm.swappiness`, it showed that `vm.swappiness = 10` (it was 60 before). I thought to change a `sysctl` setting, you had to do `sysctl -w [variable]` such as `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10`.

Is there a difference between `sysctl vm.swappiness=10` and `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10`?

I thought that `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10` might edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` directly, but that does not seem to be the case because when I entered `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10` and then looked at `/etc/sysctl.conf`, `vm.swappiness` was still set to 60. Then, when I did `sysctl -p`, `vm.swappiness` became 60 again.

So additionally, does `sysctl -w` configure `/etc/sysctl.conf` in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re: *Is there a difference between `sysctl vm.swappiness=10` and `sysctl -w vm.swappiness=10`?*

No.

re: *So additionally, does `sysctl -w` configure /etc/sysctl.conf in any way?*

No.

---

To edit /etc/sysctl.conf with a GUI text editor:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/sysctl.conf`

Otherwise use pico, nano, vim, or other favorite editor.

---

See `man sysctl` for more info.

---

Be careful when setting vm.swappiness. A low value favors RAM, where a high value favors swap.

Examples:

With 4G RAM, setting vm.swappiness=10 is nuts. With a large enough swap, setting vm.swappiness greater than 60 (the default) might make some sense.

With 32G RAM, and a HDD for swap, setting vm.swappiness=10 might make some sense.